# Как сделать интерфейс текстовому тесту написанному на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сразу скажу что Python только начал изучать. Есть тесты написанные в файле .txt и написан код чтоб их запускать. Хочу тестам придать интерфейс! Чтоб высвечивался вопрос и выбирать(либо печатать) вариант ответа номером варианта.В конце чтоб показывал количество правильных ответов.В программе все реализовано,но хочу придать ей интерфейс. Также подскажите как можно сделать чтоб таймер был? Чтоб тесты на время сдавать.Всем спасибо)

```
Пример теста:
Время защитного действия пря работе средней тяжести?
4 ч
2 ч
6 ч
1    # это номер ответа
```

Код:

```
ball = 0
kol = 0
f = open(u'D:/q.txt','r')
while True:
    vopros = f.readline().strip()
    if(not vopros):
        break
    otvet1 = f.readline().strip()
    otvet2 = f.readline().strip()
    otvet3 = f.readline().strip()
    kod = f.readline().strip()

    print(vopros)
    print('1. '+otvet1)
    print('2. '+otvet2)
    print('3. '+otvet3)
    k = str(input('Веведите код правильного ответа и нажмите Enter/n'))

    kol = kol+1
    if(k==kod):
        ball=ball+1
print('Вы ответили правильно на ' + str(ball) + ' из ' + str(kol) + ' вопросов')
```

---

Есть попытка на tkinter,но с ошибкой

```
from random import shuffle
from tkinter import *

def count1(event):
    global ans1, answers, score
    if ans1 == answers[0]:
        score += 1


def count2(event):
    global ans1, answers, score
    if ans1 == answers[1]:
        score += 1



def count3(event):
    global ans1, answers, score
    if ans1 == answers[0]:
        score += 1


score = 0 
tests = open(u'D:/q.txt','r',)
for i in range(0, 3):
    question = tests.readline()
    ans1 = tests.readline().strip()
    ans2 = tests.readline().strip()
    ans3 = tests.readline().strip()
    answers = [ans1, ans2, ans3]
    shuffle(answers)
    print(question)
    shuffle(answers)
    print(*answers, sep='\n')

    root = Tk()
    lab = Label(root, text=question, font="Arial 18")
    lab.pack()

    answ1 = Button(root)
    answ1['text'] = answers[0]
    answ1.bind('<Button-1>', count1)
    answ1.pack()

    answ2 = Button(root)
    answ2['text'] = answers[1]
    answ2.bind('<Button-1>', count2)
    answ2.pack()

    answ3 = Button(root)
    answ3['text'] = answers[2]
    answ3.bind('<Button-1>', count3)
    answ3.pack()

root.mainloop()
print(score)
```

Comment: "но с ошибкой" - с какой ошибкой?